# How to draw to a canvas in brython?

Tags: javascript, python, html, canvas, brython

I was recently trying out Brython and I'm having trouble figuring out how to draw a simple rectangle to a canvas.I can only find very complex examples of drawing to a canvas that don't work for me and I was unable to find a clear answer in the docs.

Could someone reading this please show me a bare-bones way of drawing a simple shape to a canvas with Brython and or show me something to get me on the right track?

Comment: The example posted [here](http://agentultra.com/2014/05/24/python-and-canvas2d-with-brython/) seems simple enough. `ctx.fillRect(x, y, 100.0, 100.0)` is the line that actually draws the rectangle, although you need to set the canvas up correctly first of course.

Answer (score 1):

You have some examples based on a library called [brython-bryplot](https://bitbucket.org/kikocorreoso/brython-bryplot) in [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/kikocorreoso/brython-bryplot/raw/528fa4116d1f8fd1f2ab44feb537d63778edb5d5/Testing_Bryplot.ipynb) IPython/jupyter notebook (it uses a magic function called [brythonmagic](https://github.com/kikocorreoso/brythonmagic)).

You could use directly the brython-bryplot library or you can have a look at the *[base.py](https://bitbucket.org/kikocorreoso/brython-bryplot/src/528fa4116d1f8fd1f2ab44feb537d63778edb5d5/bryplot/base.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)* module to check how shapes and text are implemented.

If you find any issues just let me know as I'm the developer of brython-bryplot, brythonmagic,... :-D